# How can I work with vectors if I don't initialize it first?

Tags: c++, lambda, stl, c++17, stdvector

I am working with `<algorithm>` library in C++.
I have an exercise with `std::vector`.

How can I use vector if I don't initialize it first like this `std::vector<int>` `v(10,0);` ?

```
std::vector<int> vec;
int i = 0;
std::generate_n(vec, 10, [int& i](){i += 10; return i});
```

I want it to be `vec={10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100}`

Comment: Do you mean [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)? Or how to [initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) (and [`std::back_insert_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_insert_iterator)), which performs `push_back` on the container to insert elements. E.g.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
vec.reserve(10); // if the size could be determined in advance
int i=0;
std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 10, [&i](){i+=10; return i;} );
```

Comment: Thanks, and if I want to copy some elements to other array, I don't know which size would be, how can I do it ? Thanks

Comment: @newstudent If the size can't be known in advance, then just not using `reserve` and let `std::vector` growing by itself.

Comment: @newstudent Even after using `reserve` it's still empty; using `std::back_inserter` together should be fine for this case.

Comment: If I want to print r value that should be sum of reciprocal values is this code good? double r; std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[&r](int i){ r+=1/i; } ); or should I do it some other way

Comment: @newstudent You should initialize `r` as `double r = 0.0`, and note the result of `1/i` would be `int` and get truncated, you can change it to `1.0 / i`.